# SQL select from tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select, command

I've got tables:

```
Table1=   USER_ID        ITEM_ID
             1              12
             1              13
             2              12
             3              12
             3               1
             3               2
```

etc..

And second table:

```
Products = ITEM_ID      PRICE 
               1           1.3
               2           0.1
               4           22
               12          33
               13          45
```

It is just example. How can I get ID's of clients who paid more than average order value?

I tried many times, but I always get errors.

Comment: please post the SQL you've tried

Comment: What do you mean by 'average order value'?

Answer (score 1):

You can do a `JOIN` between the tables and comparing the average price with specific user price paid like

```
select t1.user_id
from table1 t1
join products p on t1.item_id = p.item_id
group by t1.user_id
having p.price > avg(p.price);
```